# simulation of subscription service in excel

Tags: excel, simulation

Assuming there are 20 times on a month that a bus with a capacity of 8 drives from A to B and that there are Y subscriptions for the bus service, how does one simulate the events of people wanting to take a bus at a certain day exceeding the capacity of the bus? Knowing that on average a person would take the bus X times per month?

How do you translate the people on average taking the bus X times per month to a distribution of how many people will take the bus on a certain day?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Probability - may be more sited to Mathematics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that the demand is constant for each customer, independent from trip to trip, and that customers are independent of each other and travel individually (no groups). Under those assumptions, if customer k has an average rate of n<sub>k</sub> trips per month, and a month contains 20 trips, there is a probability p<sub>k</sub> = n<sub>k</sub> / 20 that that customer will want to go on any particular trip.  For each of the Y customers generate U, a Uniform(0,1) random number. If U <= p<sub>k</sub>, add this customer to that day's total demand. Finally, create an indicator variable E: if the total demand exceeds 8, E = 1, otherwise E = 0. Lather, rinse, repeat for as many days as you want to study.  The average of the E's is an estimate of the proportion of trips for which demand exceeded capacity.